# How to prevent *locked* parent scroll-view from scrolling when nested child scroll-view scrolls to end of its view?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

In a react-native project, there is a parent flatlist/scrollview. inside each item in this parent list, there exists a nested scroll view.

Expected behavior: When the parent scroll view is locked, the parent should NEVER scroll, only the child scrollview should be allowed to scroll. and when the outer bound of the child scroll view is met (meaning youve scrolled to the bottom or all the way back to the top of child view), the parent remains *locked*

What actually happens: with parent view scroll-locked, scrolling the child scrollview to the very bottom/top will scroll the parent scroll view, once the child scroll view reaches its scroll-boundary

Steps to reproduce behavior:

1. flick one of the child scroll views downward until it reaches the bottom
2. (even though youve reached the downward boundary) attempt to scroll the child down even more
3. observe the fact the parent scroll view now scrolls instead, even though the parent scroll view is *locked*

How can the parent scroll view be truly prevented from scrolling when nested-scroll-view reaches the end of its view?

only noticed this on android, but could possibly exist on ios as well.

here is a minimum reproducible example: https://staging.snack.expo.dev/b3XuJ6iA3

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me. I have enabled scrolling for the parent view in your snack again and it works exactly as I would expect it to work: Focusing a list item and then start scrolling, scrolls the selected inner scroll view. Focusing the parent list and then start scrolling, scroll the outer scrollview. What behavior do you want to achieve? Disabling the parent scrollview can't be the expected behavior.

Comment: thanks @DavidScholz , check my edit for further explanation of expected behavior

Comment: Well this is indeed interesting. This happens on Android but not on iOS.

Comment: May https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent would help solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting multiple `ScrollViews` inside a `FlatList`, which is a convenience wrapper around `ScrollView` (compare with [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)) , but you are setting `nestedScrolEnabled` to true in the child `ScrollViews`. You  need to set it on the parent `ScrollView` (the `FlatList`).

The following code completely disables scrolling for the parent `FlatList` while allowing scrolling in all nested `ScrollViews`.

```js
const _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 300, borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 1, marginBottom: 20}}> 
        <Text> Non scroll View area </Text>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: 500, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 3}}></ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList data={data} renderItem={_renderItem} scrollEnabled={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is a working [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/scroll-view-bug) of your code with the changes mentioned above which I have successfully tested on Android (Samsung Galaxy S9) and iOS (iPhone 12).